# How to return an empty ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relation

If I have a scope with a lambda and it takes an argument, depending on the value of the argument, I might know that there will not be any matches, but I still want to return a relation, not an empty array:

```
scope :for_users, lambda { |users| users.any? ? where("user_id IN (?)", users.map(&:id).join(',')) : [] }
```

What I really want is a "none" method, the opposite of "all", that returns a relation that can still be chained, but results in the query being short-circuited.

Comment: If you just let the query, run it will return a relation: User.where('id in (?)', []).class => ActiveRecord::Relation. Are you trying to avoid the query altogether?

Comment: Correct. If I know there can't possibly be any matches, ideally, the query could be avoided altogether. I simply added this to ActiveRecord::Base: "def self.none; where(:id => 0); end"

Seems to work just fine for what I need.

Comment: > Are you trying to avoid the query altogether? 
would totally make sense, kind of lame we need to hit DB for that

Answer (score 563, accepted):

There is a now a "correct" mechanism in Rails 4:

```
>> Model.none 
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: So far this hasn't been back ported to 3.2 or earlier. Only edge (4.0)

Comment: Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none

Comment: Just tried with Rails 4.0.5 and it's working. This feature  made it to the Rails 4.0 release.

Comment: And is there a relation that returns all results? `Model.all` returns an array ...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger `Model.scoped` does what you're looking for in rails 3.

Comment: As of Rails 4.0.5,  `Model.none` doesn't work.  You need to use one of your *real* model names, e.g. `User.none` or what-have-you.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger that is not correct, at least in 4.2.5, `Model.all.class` is a ActiveRecord_Relation as well as `Model.none.class`. So it's safe to pass on to other methods that will transform the query.

Comment: Yes, that's new from Rails 4.

Comment: And this not even hitting the database which is a big plus!

Comment: Do we compare `#length` to zero to check if empty? Will `#empty?` initiate SQL based count?

Comment: Also, use **users.pluck(:id)**, much faster!

Comment: With rails 4.1.8 this does not work when passing to an other where clause: Driver.where(company_id: Company.none) results in all driver records. Passing where('0=1') will work. This is fixed though in rails 5+ (im not sure which version exactly they fixed it)

Answer (score 76):

A more portable solution that doesn't require an "id" column and doesn't assume there won't be a row with an id of 0:

```
scope :none, where("1 = 0")
```

I'm still looking for a more "correct" way.

Comment: Yeah I'm really surprised that these answers are the best we have.  I think ActiveRecord/Arel must still be pretty immature.  If I had to go through perambulations to create an empty array in Ruby I'd be really annoyed.  Same thing here, basically.

Comment: Although somewhat hackish, this _is_ the correct way for Rails 3.2. For Rails 4, see @steveh7 's other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10001043/307308

Comment: `scope :none, -> { where("false") }`

Answer (score 46):

## Coming in Rails 4

In Rails 4, a chainable `ActiveRecord::NullRelation` will be returned from calls like `Post.none`.

Neither it, nor chained methods, will generate queries to the database.

According to the comments:

> The returned ActiveRecord::NullRelation inherits from
>   Relation and implements the Null Object pattern. It is an object with
>   defined null behavior and always returns an empty array of records
>   without quering the database.

See the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dc126cfd6f664f92b5a522bd98fbf39ff474785f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L495).

Answer (score 43):

You can add a scope called "none":

```
scope :none, where(:id => nil).where("id IS NOT ?", nil)
```

That will give you an empty ActiveRecord::Relation

You could also add it to ActiveRecord::Base in an initializer (if you want):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.none
   where(arel_table[:id].eq(nil).and(arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil)))
 end
end
```

Plenty of ways to get something like this, but certainly not the best thing to keep in a code base.  I have used the scope :none when refactoring and finding that I need to guarantee an empty ActiveRecord::Relation for a short time.

Comment: `where('1=2')` might be bit more concise

Comment: In case you don't scroll down to the new 'correct' answer: `Model.none` is how you'd do this.

Answer (score 26):

```
scope :none, limit(0)
```

Is a dangerous solution because your scope might be chained upon.

User.none.first

will return the first user. It's safer to use

```
scope :none, where('1 = 0')
```

Comment: This one is the right one 'scope :none, where('1 = 0')'. the other one will fail if you have pagination

Answer (score 15):

I think I prefer the way this looks to the other options:

```
scope :none, limit(0)
```

Leading to something like this:

```
scope :users, lambda { |ids| ids.present? ? where("user_id IN (?)", ids) : limit(0) }
```

Comment: I prefer this one. I'm not sure why `where(false)` wouldn't do the job--it leaves the scope unchanged.

Comment: Beware that `limit(0)` will be overridden if you call `.first` or `.last` later in the chain, since Rails will append `LIMIT 1` to that query.

Comment: @aceofspades where(false) doesn't work (Rails 3.0) but where('false') does. Not that you probably care now it's 2013 :)

Comment: Thanks @Ritchie, since then I think we also have the `none` relation as mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

Use scoped:

```
scope :for_users, lambda { |users| users.any? ? where("user_id IN (?)", users.map(&:id).join(',')) : scoped }
```

But, you can also simplify your code with:

```
scope :for_users, lambda { |users| where(:user_id => users.map(&:id)) if users.any? }
```

If you want an empty result, use this (remove the if condition):

```
scope :for_users, lambda { |users| where(:user_id => users.map(&:id)) }
```

Comment: Returning "scoped" or nil doesn't achieve what I want, which is to limit the results to zero. Returning "scoped" or nil has no effect on the scope (which is useful in some cases, but not in mine). I came up with my own answer (see comments above).

Comment: I added a simple solution for you to return an empty result as well :)

Answer (score 2):

There are also variants, but all of these are making request to db

```
where('false')
where('null')
```

Comment: BTW Note that these must be strings. `where(false)` or `where(nil)` is simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and so that's:

```
scope :for_users, lambda { |users| users.any? ? where("user_id IN (?)", users.map(&:id).join(',')) : User.none }
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none

Correct me if I'm wrong.