# Only push objects into array if the scope returns records, not a blank

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a loop that hits a couple scopes and then pushes the results into an array. The problem I have is if no records match the scope(s) it still returns an **ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []**. How do I filter these out so I don't get them in my array?

Example:

```
class Snack
  belongs_to :member

  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
  scope :snacktypefind, -> (snacktypefind) { where(snacktype: snacktypefind) }
end

class Member
  has_many :snacks

 def find_snacks(snacktypes)
    returnarray = []
    snacktypes.each do |snacktype|
       returnarray << self.snacks.red.snacktypefind(snacktype)
    end
  return returnarray
 end

end
```

Then say in a view I want to:

```
 <% @member.find_snacks(['bannana','orange']).each do |snack| %>
    <li>snack.name</li>
 <% end %>
```

In the above case I would want the array to be [] but instead it is:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>, #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>]
```

What silly thing am I doing wrong this time? Thanks again for any help you can give!

Comment: Why not push them if `.length > 0`?

Comment: I tried that and got an error when records came back since they didn't have a length function. I might of done it wrong though.

Comment: You could try `count`. Are you trying to actually `concat` values onto the array, or maintain an array of scopes that have values, or...?

Comment: If you could share your actual code instead of a fake example that would go a long way toward helping us answer your question.

Comment: Try `+=` instead of `<<`?

Comment: How about `created_array = ['apple','orange'].map { |fruit| ClassName.scope_type(fruit).... }.reject { |fruit| ... }` (or `select`). Admission: I don't know Rails.

Comment: @Jordan, I'll try to clear up the example some. Hard to grab existing code as there is a lot going on that makes it long and confusing.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact opposite of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877931/how-to-return-an-empty-activerecord-relation

Comment: @MechDog that post is to return an Empty Relation you want to return a populated Relation. It is really not the exact opposite. You would have to monkey patch `Array` to get similar functionality which I could certainly write an example for but i believe your real problem stems from a misunderstanding about query syntax.

Comment: No argument that I might not understand the query syntax. The problem I have is that I need the loop to do other things to determine if I want to push it in. The solution you propose would fix my simplified version, but I really need to run the .each on the array that I feed in for the code I'm working on. Its a tough one to layout as there is jsut WAY to much code to layout the full example so I tried to simplify the code to get to the base issue. The double edged sword is there are then solutions that work for the simplified that are hard to apply to the real issue.

Comment: I wish I could help and I am sure I could but without looking at what you truly need, it will be difficult. I would sincerely recommend query method chaining because the current handle will have extreme performance impacts based on the number of queries it can/does run.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. I'm looking up and reading some things to see if I can clarify better. I think the heart of it appears that I thought I was receiving a Array of Snack objects back, but I'm really receiving back and AssociationRelation Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow you just made it way easier with extra code how about this

```
class Member
  has_many :snacks

  def find_snacks(snacktypes)
    snacks.red.snacktypefind(snacktypes)
  end

end
```

This turns into

```
"SELECT snacks.* FROM snacks WHERE snacks.member_id = YOUR_MEMBER_ID AND snacks.color = 'red' AND snacks.snacktype IN (YOUR snacktypes array)"
```

Currently your implementation we will call it "query and push" has drawbacks.

First this will create multiple miniature collections probably composed of single objects. This will be hell to iterate as you will have to nest iteration to actually access the object.
Second this will create multiple queries 1 for each `snacktype` which will degrade performance.

What you really want is to chain query methods to narrow everything down to a single `ActiveRecord::Relation` that will contain just the elements you need. This will execute a single query and when you iterate the piped object will be the actual object you want to access and not another `ActiveRecord::Relation` which would have to be iterated again.

[ActiveRecord Query Methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) the great part about scopes and query chains are that they don't get executed until the chain is complete allowing you to easily add and remove conditions in a very granular manner. This way you can target the data in the database explicitly instead of loading it into memory and cleaning it up from there.

Comment: How does the snacktypes get to the variable snacktype? Does rails take plurals and iterate them? Always amazing some of the things it does! Nevermind, I missed the correction. Sorry about that. Trying it now

Comment: using the *(splat) operator it will take your arguments like this `('banana','orange')` and make them an array `['banana','orange']` when this is passed to the query method `where` as a `Hash`. e.g. `where(snacktype:['banana','orange'])` it sees this is an `Array` and creates an `IN` statement rather than an `=` statement.

Comment: I corrected the code, it was supposed to be an Array going in. Thanks for the info! I've tried it and I still seem to be getting back #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> sometimes when I chain certain ones together. I'll double check. Shame they don't have a way to just get rid of the #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> instead of all this hoop jumping.

Comment: @MechDog I think it has more to do with your implementation. There is no need to iterate and push this creates multiple issues. 1 you end up with multiple mini-collections (not great for iterating), 2 it creates multiple queries 1 for each "snacktype". What you want to do is chain all your query methods together so it runs 1 query that returns the exact results in a single `ActiveRecord::Relation` that way you can just iterate over that. I it is empty the iteration just won't happen. Simple and easy. If you add more detail as to the issue I will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!! Took me a while, but think I'm back on track. I had a where clause using SQL that I think was messing up the automatic array use. I changed it to use the rails way of listing joined tables and it all appears to work now. Thanks for all the time you put in! I learned a lot more then I bargained for which is always great!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
 def find_snacks(snacktypes)
  returnarray = self.snacks.none

  snacktypes.each do |snacktype|
   returnarray += self.snacks.red.snacktypefind(snacktype)
 end
 return returnarray
end
```

Only works for rails 4 because of the **.none**, but I have no rails 3 projects so I figured that was okay.