# How was ActiveRecord "none" method implemented with NullRelation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to understand the `none` method introduced in `Rails4`.

Here is the implementation from `Rails API`

```
def none
  where("1=0").extending!(NullRelation)
end
```

And I found similar implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063086/5076451) in `Rails3` way.

```
scope :none, where(:id => nil).where("id IS NOT ?", nil)
```

Can anyone help me understand how this method was implemented with `NullRelation` in `Rails4` and advantages?

Comment: In Rails 3 if you use the ``scope :none``, it will hit the database and try to load data. But if you use rails 4 ``none`` method it wont hit the database.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first check [ActiveRecord::NullRelation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3bcb31499862d2a11bf59e449c6d0dc0930962a4/activerecord/lib/active_record/null_relation.rb)

They basically set to constant values all methods, so whatever you are going to use, won't hit the database.

Remember that when you chain methods over a relation you **get a new relation** every time, which means, once you hit `none`, all future methods will try to build a relation from that one. It's easy to imagine that they won't find anything in the database and will just keep returning `self` (the `NullRelation`).

In addition, considering that you already linked the current implementation, is pretty clear that they will keep returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but obviously it won't find anything due to the `'1=0'` approach. The key point however is in the `extending!` method, which will overwrite the methods for **ActiveRecord::Relation instance** (not for all relations, so that's like a singleton instance in Ruby) by forcing it not to hit the database (the `exec_queries` is replaced with a simple empty array as return value).

Comment: I wonder there are bunch of methods defined in the `ActiveRecord::Relation` module. I am trying to understand how they work and how `extending!` method does the job. Thanks this information helps me.

Comment: I didn't check `extending!` implementation but from the name, it's basically an "include" but for instance only. I believe they overwrite the relation methods which hit the database with those in `NullRelation`, and that's it, that relation instance will never hit the database and will never return records.